# $R\subset S\times S$ for $S=\{1,2,3\}$: A Graph-Theoretic Approach

Tags: graph-theory, relations, equivalence-relations

So I am given the relation $R=\{(1,1),(2,2),(3,3),(1,2),(1,3)\}$ and asked which of the properties reflexive, symmetric, or transitive are held in the relation, but what I am thinking is that this can be represented as a graph like this:

[image]

Is there a theorem that states that all equivalence classes must be connected in some particular fashion?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your directed graph for $R$ is correct. From it you should be able quite easily to see that $R$ has exactly two of the three properties.

The answer to your actual question is *yes*. If $C$ is an equivalence class of an equivalence relation $R$, and $G$ is the directed graph of $R$, then $C$ together with its associated edges will be a connected component of $G$: every possible directed edge between vertices of $C$ will be present in $G$. Moreover, there will be no edges between different equivalence classes. Conversely, if a directed graph has that structure, it’s the digraph associated with an equivalence relation on its vertices, with two vertices being related precisely in case they are joined by an edge.

Comment: Wait, which of the two are you referring to? I have that only one holds, namely reflexivity. How can $R$ be symmetric if $(2,1)\not\in R$? Further, how can $R$ be transitive if $(2,3)\not\in R$?

Comment: Do you have a reference to your assertion? That is, your "*yes*."

Comment: @Loie: The relation is transitive. You cannot find $a,b,c\in S$ such that $a\mathbin{R}b\mathbin{R}c$ and $a\not\mathbin{R}c$. In terms of the graph, using $a\to b$ to mean that there is a directed edge from $a$ to $b$, you cannot find vertices $a,b,c$ such that $a\to b\to c$, but $a\not\to c$. // No, I’ve no reference at hand for the assertion, but it’s very easy to prove.

Comment: The only instances of $a\to b\to c$ in your graph all have one of the forms $a\to a\to a$, $a\to a\to b$, and $a\to b\to b$. To get a violation of transitivity, you’d have to have either $a\to b\to a$ with $a\not\to a$, which you don’t or $a\to b\to c$ with $a,b$, and $c$ all distinct (and $a\not\to c$), which you don’t.

Comment: @LoieBenedicte: you are correct it isn't symmetric